# How to stop a sprite from going out of the device display Libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

i'm making a flappy bird clone app and i want to ask for your help, how can i stop the bird from going out of the device display from the  top side?

I have this code to prevent the bird from going out of display from the bottom side and it works perfectly fine

```
if(birdY > 0 || velocity < 0) {
Velocity = velocity + gravity

birdY -= velocity 

}
```

Comment: I have a value called gravity but currently I can’t acves al the codes

Comment: And also velocity and everything you see is are variables defined already but anyway do you have another way to stop the bird from going out of the device display from top

Comment: Man the code is written in android studio.. if? What’s so weird about the if statement

Answer (score 0):

In your `render()` method, put this code to update the bird's position:

```
velocity += gravity*delta;//gravity must be negative
birdY += velocity*delta;//delta is the amount of time (in seconds) since the last frame
```

After you've changed the bird's position, put this code:

```
if(birdY < 0){
    birdY = 0;
}else if(birdY > screenHeight-birdHeight){
    birdY = screenHeight-birdHeight;
}
```

You must initialize the variables `screenHeigth`, `birdHeight`, `velocity` and `gravity` beforehand. `birdHeight` is the height of the bird's texture.